# how to use mongodb in angular 4 app

Tags: mongodb, angular

1: Is there any method to connect mongodb with angular 4 app. i learned firebase instead of mongodb. angular 4 is using angularfire2 to connect with firebase database. is there any imports or APIs which will solve my problem( is there any tutorials which will teach me mongodb works with angular 4).

2: what really mlab is ?
please explain this ...

Comment: You must read about client/server architecture to get better insights.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to use mongodb on cloud ([Mongo DB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas)) directly inside Angular through their [MongoDB Stitch](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/stitch) service. MongoDB Stitch sits in between MongoDB and Angular, providing methods for you to access the DB, provide authentication plus more. Unfortunately, it only supports MongoDB Atlas 
 and not local databases for now.There are available tutorials on the site for you to look into.

The stitch library is pretty straight forward, but it is written on pure JS no TS support. The only issue I have right now  is how to use the 'mongodb-stitch' npm package instead of including the hosted JS lib on the html page. I have posted this [concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417758/using-mongodb-stitch-library-in-angular-4) in case you are interested.

Answer (score 3):

**How to connect MongoDB to Angular 4:**

You can access Mongo with the help of Mangoose and Node Express. For more details on Mangoose use the link: `http://mongoosejs.com/docs/`. Node Express will be used to create the backend of the Angular 4 Application. All connections to the MongoDB will be handled by the node server. Check the documentation of MongoDB for more details:

```
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/the-modern-application-stack-part-3-building-a-rest-api-using-expressjs
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb is not directly accessible from browser/frontend. You need to have a backend to use mongodb.

- Mlab is a mongodb hosting service.

Comment: than what should i do. install node js as a backend or what

Answer (score -1):

You need to understand one concept how web based application works 
**CLIENT**, **Server**, **DATABASE**.

When you make response to **server** it ask server to request  to database and get **required data**. After server request to database it gives to server data via **response**. At last data from server via response serve to your client via response

**It important to have server in middle of database and CLIENT**