# Using mongodb-stitch library in Angular 4

Tags: mongodb, angular, typescript

Im been trying the MongoDB Stitch service in Angular, so far Im able to use the service. However, the only way I could connect to the service is by including the js library hosted in AWS on the html page.

There is a mongodb-stitch npm package available and there are sample pages on mongodb tutorial on how to use it. But this is a pure JS library (no TS support) and I have tried several ways (using require, installing typings of the lib (not available), using @types) to no avail.

Anyone tried this on Ng4? Would love to have the steps you did to use the 'mongodb-stitch' package the create a service.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer suggests instantiating a new instance of `StitchClient` which is something that MongoDB have explicitly advised against in the [Official API Documentation](https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-sdks/js/docs/master/index.html#overview) - and with reason, since there is a factory method available for that purpose. So, (after installing `mongodb-stitch`), the following code would help you get started in `component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { StitchClientFactory } from "mongodb-stitch";

let appId = 'authapp-****';

@Component({
selector: "app-mongo-auth",
templateUrl: "./mongo-auth.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./mongo-auth.component.css"]
})

export class MongoAuthComponent implements OnInit {

mClient;

ngOnInit() {
  this.mClient = StitchClientFactory.create(appId);
}
```

And you can then use this for whatever purpose you want, such as for implementing sign-in with Google

```
gLogin(){
this.mClient.then(stitchClient => {
  stitchClient.authenticate("google");
})
```

Comment: Thanks so far! I fear I am stuck with another question. Can mongodb-stitch, using promises, be combined with Angulars Obervables or how would I listen to the result of, for example, .find() on the collection?

Answer (score 1):

not sure whether the question is still relevant considering it was asked two months ago but anyway...

As you pointed out you can use 
`npm install --save mongodb-stitch`
to install the package and since there is no TS binding you can declare the *stitch* library as *any*

For example:

```
    declare var stitch: any;

    export class MyService implements OnInit {
    db;

    client;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.client = new stitch.StitchClient('<check the stitch app page for proper value>');
        this.db = this.client.service('mongodb', 'mongodb-atlas').db('<the db name goes here>');
        this.client.login();
    }

    save() {
        this.db.collection('<collection name>').insertOne({key : 'value'}).then(() => console.log("All done"));
    }

  }
```

Comment: is there somewhere example coding in the web? imports, app.module.ts?

Comment: For the Stitch API I use the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/). Everything else is just Angular. There is nothing specific. As mentioned before - there is not TypeScript binding so you can: `declare var stitch: any`, to be able to use Stitch

Answer (score 1):

the previous answers are functional, but i wanna share a example using a service injectable.

service.ts

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Jsonp, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

import { StitchClientFactory } from "mongodb-stitch";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class Service {  
  constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) { }    
  client;
  connect(){
    this.client = new StitchClientFactory.create("App ID");  // Slitch apps > Clients > App ID
    this.client.then(stitchClient => stitchClient.login())
      .then((stitchClient) => console.log('logged in as: ' + stitchClient))
      .catch(e => console.log('error: ', e));
  }
  all() {
    this.connect();     
    return this.client.then(stitchClient => {
      let db = stitchClient.service('mongodb', 'mongodb-atlas').db("database Name"); // Slitch apps > mongodb-atlas > Name database.Collection
      let itemsCollection = db.collection('name collection'); // Slitch apps > mongodb-atlas > Name database.Collection        
      console.log(itemsCollection.find().execute());
      return itemsCollection.find().execute();                  
    })
     .then(result => {return result})
     .catch(e => console.log('error: ', e));          
   }
 }
```

after make the previous file, you must create a module to receive the data, so:

module.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { StitchClientFactory } from "mongodb-stitch";
import { Service }          from 'service'; // previous code

declare var stitch: any;

@Component({  
  template: '
    <ul class="demo-list-icon mdl-list">
      <li class="mdl-list__item" *ngFor="let item of data | async">
         <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
           <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-icon">{{propiedad.nombre}}</i>            
         </span>
      </li>
   </ul>
  '  
 })
 export class MainComponent implements OnInit {  
   data: Observable<[]>;
   constructor(private Service: service) {
   }
   ngOnInit() {     
     this.propiedades = this.Service.all();
   }  
}
```

important, you don´t must forget to add service on module.ts intitial declarations.

[mongodb Atlas](https://cloud.mongodb.com/)

[mongodb-stitch vía NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-stitch)

[Documentation mongoDB Stitch.](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/getting-started/)

Sure!